# An error has occured {1}{0} while importing solution in CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

> Dynamics CRM Error: Importing Solutions in CRM 2016– An Error has Occurred {1}{0}.

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the log file ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can download import log file. Maybe it will give you more understanding of what is happening.
2. You can get traces from CRM. It can provide you with more information about error you have. If you have 2016 On-Prem check following: https://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/ or http://www.qgate.co.uk/knowledge/how-to-enable-tracing-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/

Comment: hi i am using dynamic crm online

Comment: Is there any additional information in import log? It is available in Online version also. You can download it on the final page of import withard (The page where error is displayed). There are two pages in import log. Please see the second one for details. Could share line from import log?

Comment: I have imported the managed solution, after choosing the file and clicking next  it shows "an error has occured {1}{0}"   import  button is disabled .     Like this [1]:https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2550ac2f-83df-4117-ac0e-8b34a860fe72/an-error-has-occured-10-while-importing-solution-in-crm-2011?forum=crm

Comment: It looks like there are so many reasons for such behavior. And may be fastest way is to use support as following guys did: https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/055185dd-c0a4-4300-aabc-c04c8b6a9cf2/an-error-occured-10-in-solution-import-dialog-crm-online?forum=crmdevelopment